# Как найти среднее (медиану) из трёх чисел?

Tags: java, алгоритм

Имеется три числа: 10, 20, 30. Как найти среднее из них (не самое большое и не самое маленькое), без множества условий?

Comment: А у вас математика в школе была уже? Там про среднее арифметическое рассказывали?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, а в вопросе про среднее арифметическое и не спрашивают :)

Comment: именно для 3 чисел?

Comment: @Nikolay, да, для трех

Comment: Немного не ясен вопрос: вы хотите среднее по положению или которое наиболее близкое к среднеарифметическому?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов: вопрос о median, а не mean. Связанный вопрос [Minimum no. of comparisons to find median of 3 numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17158667/4279)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Отсортировать и взять среднее.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = new int[] {31, 6, 13};
    Arrays.sort(numbers);
    System.out.println(numbers[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
int max = Math.max(Math.max(a,b), c);
int min = Math.min(Math.min(a,b), c);
int mid = a + b + c - (min + max);
```

Comment: Можно даже так int mid = a ^ b ^ c ^ min ^ max;

Comment: [`median = max(min(a,b), min(max(a,b),c));`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/712770/23044)

Answer (score 3):

Можно через условие тернарными операторами

```
int mid =  (a > b)? ((c<b)?b:((c<a)?c:a)): ( (a>c)?a:(b>c)?c:b);
```

Answer (score 1):

решение без сортировки, используя сравнение

```
int a = scanner.nextInt();
int b = scanner.nextInt();
int c = scanner.nextInt();
if ((a - b) * (c - a) >= 0) {              // a >= b and a <= c OR a <= b and a >= c
    System.out.print(a);
} else if ((b - a) * (c - b) >= 0) {       // b >= a and b <= c OR b <= a and b >= c
    System.out.print(b);
} else {
    System.out.print(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Держи ещё вариант с одним ифом, а не несколькими:

```
private int middleOfThree(int[] input) {
    int x = Math.max(input[0], input[1]);
    int y = Math.max(input[0], input[2]);
    if (x == y) {
        return Math.max(input[1], input[2]);
    } else {
        return Math.min(x, y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import static java.lang.Math.*;


int[] digits = {20, 10, 30};
System.out.println(max(max(min(digits[0], digits[1]), min(digits[1], digits[2])), min(digits[0], digits[2])));
```

Comment: можно до [4 min/max](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/712770/23044) упростить вместо 5

Answer (score 0):

Вам в любом случае придется использовать условия - пусть даже внешне они будут скрыты в вызовах готовых методов для сортировки (`Collections.sort`, `Arrays.sort` и т.п.) или получения мин./макс. значений (`Math.min`, `Math.max` и т.п.). Лучше написать простенькую функцию с парой условий - это гарантированно будет работать быстрее.

```
private static int getMed(int a, int b, int c) {
    return (a >= b && a <= c) || (a <= b && a >= c) ? a : 
          ((b >= a && b <= c) || (b <= a && b >= c) ? b : c);
}
```

Comment: есть решение без  ветвления, используя только [min, max](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/712770/23044), которые могут  использовать [SSE min/max CPU векторные инструкции](https://godbolt.org/g/gnDLTr) (код [@Gyorgy Szekely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937732/number-of-comparisons-made-in-median-of-3-function/19027761#comment79067353_19027761))

Answer (score 0):

Решение, используя [сеть сортировки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8), построенной на основе метода пузырьков, из [ответа @Gyorgy Szekely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19027761/4279):

```
int median = Math.max(Math.min(a, b), Math.min(Math.max(a, b), c));
```

Полный пример:

```
public class MedianOf3 {
  public static void main(String[] argv) {
      System.out.println(median(10, 20, 30));
  }
  public static int median(int a, int b, int c) {
      return Math.max(Math.min(a, b), Math.min(Math.max(a, b), c));
  }
}
```

Вывод:

```
20
```

См. [Fastest way of finding the middle value of a triple?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1582356/4279)

Answer (score 0):

Вот что-то похожее решил на codewars

```
import static java.util.stream.IntStream.of;
interface Kata {
  static double find_average(int[] array) {
    return of (array).average().orElse(3);
  }
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scr = new Scanner (System.in);
        int x = scr.nextInt();
        int y = scr.nextInt();
        int z = scr.nextInt();
        if ((x >= y & x <= z) || (x <= y & x >= z)) {
            System.out.print(x);
        } else  if ((y >= x & y <= z) || (y <= x & y >= z)){
            System.out.println(y);
        } else 
            System.out.println(z);
    }
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]