# Сортировка по убыванию 3 целых числа > 0 без if и min/max функций

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x

Вывести 3 числа в порядке убывания без использования функций, и так далее. Без max(), min(), if и прочего.

Объясняю), я сегодня делал КР по питону и я сделал через sorted, а препод сказал что можно еще проще и без if и я не могу понять, что он имел ввиду.

Comment: Еще раз, вывести 3 числа в порядке убывания без использования IF?

Comment: да, возможно это связанно как-то с bool..

Comment: С bool связан if, и, похоже, вы просите невозможного

Comment: Объясняю), я сегодня делал КР по питону и я сделал через sorted, а препод сказал что можно еще проще и без if и я не могу понять, что он имел ввиду.

Comment: @andreymal Можно конечно сделать массив на N место записать число N, потом пройтись циклом и выводить элемент если он равен какому-нибудь из введенных. Формально тут не используется IF но мне кажется это бред какой-то.

Comment: @Andrew может, он имел в виду именно min и max?

Comment: Можно через прогрессию, но условие у вас не понятное, от куда например эти числа брать которые нужно вывести в порядке убывания? Что это за числа ? как их создать? рандомно ? или они уже заданы ? вы условие сначала нормально оформите. И вообще этот форум не для того что вам задачки решать на заказ.

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч какя прогрессия для 1 17 -8?

Comment: 3 целых числа > 0.

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов это что за три числа? я например могу написать такие которые в формулу прогрессии легко впишутся, автор ничего про числа не сказал, какими они должны быть.

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч а какая разница? Вы ж не уточняли для каких чисел можно "через прогрессию", вот и хотелось бы понять что тут за прогрессия...

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов мне зачем это уточнять? это автор в вопросе уточнять должен.

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч вы про прогрессию говорили? Вот и интересно узнать про прогрессию для трех произвольных чисел.

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов любой последовательности чисел для которой можно применить закон арифметической или геометрической прогрессии, автор то не слова не сказал что там за числа должны быть

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов для произвольных согласен, не какой, но опять же автор не чего про числа не сказал, я же про это ему и написал, что бы уточнил про какие числа он говорит.

Comment: А хоть сравнивать-то можно? :)

Answer (score 11):

Без ветвления (без `if`), выполняя одни и те же сравнения вне зависимости от ввода, можно отсортировать три числа `a`,`b`,`c` по убыванию, используя [сети сортировки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8):

[image: sorting network]

Значения заходят слева по проводам, выходят справа. Бо́льшие значения тонут, меньшие всплывают (по вертикальным линиям — компараторам: маx вниз, min наверх).
Без min, max функций можно использовать индексацию:

```
[[[(a, b, c), (a, c, b)], [None, (c, a, b)]],
 [[(b, a, c), None], [(b, c, a), (c, b, a)]]][a < b][a < c][b < c]
```

[Пример](https://ideone.com/Cni0tE).

`True == 1 and False == 0` в Питоне, поэтому выражение `[on_false, on_true][condition]` возвращает `on_false`, если `condition` ложно и `on_true`— если истинно.

Код возвращает одну из шести возможных перестановок: abc acb cab bac bca  cba так чтобы значения всегда шли по убыванию: `sorted([a,b,c], reverse=True)`. `None` никогда не выбирается, так как соответствует невозможным ситуациям (при корректном операторе сравнения): `c > a >= b >= c` и `c <= a < b < c`. [Тест](https://ideone.com/3AtRIi).

Связанные вопросы:

- [Как найти среднее (медиану) из трёх чисел?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/712770/23044)
- [Determining which octant has a specific point](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/95550/6143)

Comment: ну как раз сортировать и не обязательно насколько я понял )
нужно только "вывести"

Comment: @VasylKolomiets: нажмите на слово [«Пример» в ответе.](https://ideone.com/Cni0tE)

Answer (score 6):

Алгоритмически:

```
sub main {
input a,b,c
regularize(a,b)
regularize(b,c)
regularize(a,b)
print a,b,c
}

sub regularize(x,y) {
tmp=(x+y+ABS(x-y))/2
y=tmp-ABS(x-y)
x=tmp
}
```

**PS.** Желающим поправить ответ до рабочего кода - создайте свой ответ, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4):

challenge accepted

Чисто формально:

```
a, b, c = list(map(int, input("Enter 3 numbers").split())) 
l = ["" for i in range(a+b+c)] #создаем массив размер которого точно превышает максимальное из введенных чисел
l[a] = a
l[b] = b
l[c] = c
print(" ".join(str(i) for i in l[::-1]))
```

Comment: интересная идея! Только наверное надо `for i in l[::-1]`?

Comment: @MaxU да, согласен

Comment: Чисто формально `range`, `join` и `str` уже не «без использования функций» :)

Comment: @andreymal все равно ответ очень находчивый )

Comment: @andreymal а в коде интерпретатора их сколько...

Comment: мда, это точно проще чем сортед?

Comment: @VasylKolomiets нет конечно, но сказано не проще, а без if и всяких алгоритмических функций. Какое задание, такой и ответ

Comment: это не работает. Попробуйте `a=b=c=1` ввод.

Answer (score 2):

ну вот еще одно решение, которое "еще проще". Есть в модуле для куч такие функции: выдать несколько наибольших и несколька наименьших. Даже пересортировывать список в кучу не обязательно )

```
import heapq
nums = [1, 8, -4]
print(heapq.nlargest(3, nums))   # Prints [8, 1, -4]
print(heapq.nsmallest(3, nums))  # Prints [-4, 1, 8]
```

Однако интересно, что препод-то имел ввиду?

Answer (score 2):

Действительно можно проще: вы использовали функцию **sorted**, а что она делает? Помимо того, что возвращает отсортированные значения, но возвращает их в новом объекте, т.е. *создает новый объект* - а это затратно и по времени и по ресурсам:

```py
from timeit import timeit

a = [1,0,9,]
def sorted_rev(x):
    sorted(x, reverse=True)  # создаст новый объект

timeit('sorted_rev(a)', globals={'sorted_rev': sorted_rev, 'a': a})
Out: 1.8182791949984676
```

Можно задействовать метод списка **sort**, который не будет создавать новый объект, а отсортирует текущий - что выгодно и по времени и по ресурсам:

```py
from timeit import timeit

a = [1,0,9,]
def sort_rev(x):                                                                         
    x.sort(reverse=True)  # отсортирует текущий объект

timeit('sort_rev(a)', globals={'sort_rev': sort_rev, 'a': a})
Out: 0.9372297810004966
```

**Вывод: это проще, дешевле и быстрее.**

Answer (score 0):

С разрешения @Akina перепишу его код на Python

```
def regularize(x,y):
    tmp=(x+y+abs(x-y))/2
    y=tmp-abs(x-y)
    x=tmp
    return x, y

a, b, c = list(map(int, input("Enter 3 numbers ").split())) 
a, b = regularize(a,b)
b, c = regularize(b,c)
a, b = regularize(a,b)
print(*list(map(int, [a, b, c])))
```

[Пример](https://ideone.com/HgSRUU)

Comment: 1- list не нужно вызывать здесь. 2- используйте // (целое деление) вместо /  3- последнюю строчку можно упростить `print(a, b, c)`